# Покупки в приложении google play billing library

Tags: android, android-billing

Собственно проблема в следующем, все покупки в моих приложениях возвращаются обратно покупателям ровно через трое суток после покупки. Это происходит со 100% платежей. Я написал в саппорт гугл они мне ответили что после покупки надо как можно скорее подтвердить покупку и тогда платежи не будут возвращаться. Вот что конкретно они мне ответили:
"Google Play supports purchasing products from inside of your app (in-app) or outside of your app (out-of-app). In order for Google Play to ensure a consistent purchase experience regardless of where the user purchases your product, you must acknowledge all purchases that have a SUCCESS state received through the Google Play Billing Library as soon as possible after granting entitlement to the user."

Можете подсказать где конкретно они подтвердаются или нужно использовать какую то функцию в библиотеке для подтверждения. Заранее спасибо за помощь, что то ничего не нагуглил и видимо в библиотеке что то упустил.

Comment: да как вы не "нагуглили" когда в оф документации все разжевано

Comment: Я так понимаю это метод acknowledge() ?

Comment: да..............

Comment: Все уже опубликовал обнову исправленную буду тестить, год проблемы были, и тут вопросы задавал и в саппорт несколько раз, никто совет не дал. Наконец то саппорт нормально ответил в макете.